# SQL Server - list all tables without a primary key

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is it possible to produce a list of all tables within a specified database that don't have a primary key?

This is SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This really belongs more on StackOverflow rather than ServerFault, doesn't it?

Anyway, I found this script that I posted a few years back: [List all tables without a primary key](http://forums.learnsqlserver.com/SqlServerTopic31.aspx). It works for SQL 2000+.

Comment: I think it's well appropriate for SF from the dba perspective.

Comment: I'm new here and still trying to figure it all out :) I thought SO was for development and SF was for admin and I guess I got confused! I think this is definitely a DBA-level script so I think you are right. Sorry about that!

Comment: For what it's worth I did deliberate about where to put it.  My conclusion being that the required reason for wanting to know is so I can set up replication - nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 3):

yikes! information schema views are ugly.

If your database is 2005, then you should use the catalog views, as [recommended by MS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189082.aspx)

Here's my solution:

```
SELECT
* from sys.tables
WHERE object_id not in
(SELECT object_id from sys.indexes WHERE is_primary_key=1)
```

Comment: Only a one off job, so not too bothered, however have voted you up for other uses who may have this enquiry.